# Como hacer consultas de SQL server desde python?

Tags: python, sql-server

Alguien me podría ayudar por fabor, lo que pasa es que necesito hacer una consulta de una base de datos que ya está hecha en SQL server por medio de Python, mi objeivo es mostrar la información en una pantalla de tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La pregunta es demasiado ambigua.
Entiendo que lo que quieres es usar un código SQL de SQLServer dentro de python, en un dataset que ya tienes, asumo que dentro de pandas.

Si es así, puedes usar pandassql para trabajar con los datasets a través de consultas SQL, y esto ya lo tienes respondido aquí -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865608/executing-an-sql-query-over-a-pandas-dataset

Si no se trata de eso, por favor, detalla tu pregunta y especifica qué quieres hacer exactamente.

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que no sabia que libreria utilizar para realizarlo, gracias por tu aportación.